# Is it possible to configure Improved JSON SIM for a specific envelope?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

Improved JSON SIM format seems to be something fairly new and from reading the documentation it seems that, through the API, we can only create an account level configuration, meaning that we will receive events from all envelopes and only admins can create this configurations.

Is it possible to configure the webhooks for specific envelopes with non-admin users, the same way we can do it with the aggregate webhooks?

Are you planning to deprecate the other webhook models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [JSON SIM format](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/improved-json-sim-event-model/) can be set for the per-envelope webhooks. Below is a code snippet with the deliveryMode, the Events, and the format that will need to be set in the eventNotification section to enable this new format. One thing to note is this new format has a new webhook structure so would recommend testing in Demo first.

In terms of deprecating other methods we will not be deprecating XML/JSON aggregate modes for the foreseeable future but we will be launching a deprecation plan for XML SIM later this year. More details to come on that.

```
    {
"emailSubject": "Please sign the attached document",
"status": "sent",
"eventNotification": {
    "url": "https://apps.example.com/app2/webhook-listener",
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "loggingEnabled": "true",
    "deliveryMode":  "SIM",
    "events": ["envelope-sent", "envelope-resent", "envelope-delivered", "envelope-completed", "envelope-declined", "envelope-voided", "envelope-signed", "recipient-authenticationfailed", "recipient-autoresponded", "recipient-declined", "recipient-deliveryfailed", "recipient-delivered", "recipient-completed", "recipient-sent", "recipient-resent"],
    "eventData": {
        "version": "restv2.1",
        "format":  "json",
        "includeData": ["custom_fields", "extensions", "folders",
            "recipients", "powerform", "tabs", "payment_tabs"]
    }
},
"recipients": {
  "signers": [
```

…

Comment: Hey! 

Thank you for response.

I did some experiments with the webhook configurations and it seems that the "events" property is being ignored and only the "envelopeEvents" property is able to define the events we want to receive. But I was able to receive the JSON SIM events after that.

Another thing is the SIM flag in the account settings (UI -> Settings -> Account -> Updates) that affects how the webhook works. I was expecting the JSON SIM to work with that flag enabled but it only seems to allow XML SIM.

Can you confirm this on your side?