# DocuSign JSON SIM

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

According to DocuSign Connection documentation there is now [JSON SIM](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/improved-json-sim-event-model/) format.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70739688/is-it-possible-to-configure-improved-json-sim-for-a-specific-envelope), it is mentioned XML SIM will be deprecated. What does it mean for per envelope notifications? In aggregate mode both JSOn and XML will be available while in SIM mode only JSON will be available?

Also, currently when creating an envelope through the API with JSON notifications, an error is thrown if SIM is activated in the Connect page (when SIM is active in Connect page only XML SIM is possible).

If XML SIM is deprecated this year, will an error still be thrown in the above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean for per envelope notifications? In aggregate mode both JSOn and XML will be available while in SIM mode only JSON will be available?

This means that in the near future, SIM will only be available in JSON format. Both XML and JSON would still use aggregation. You can read more about the difference between aggregation and SIM [here](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/using-connects-send-individual-messages-feature)

> Also, currently when creating an envelope through the API with JSON notifications, an error is thrown if SIM is activated in the Connect page (when SIM is active in Connect page only XML SIM is possible).

Through the connect UI you can configure only SIM for XML, not for JSON. This is the reason for the error. At the moment the only way to enable SIM for JSON is through an API call. You can read more in this [guide](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/improved-json-sim-event-model/)